# Creating a dataframe by multiplying the columns of other 2 dataframes on Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So, I'm having a hard time here with a tricky task on pyspark. I need to create a new dataframe with the data from the two dataframes below. The first one is called `app_daily_users`:

| DATE | APP_1 | APP_2 | APP_3 | APP_4 | APP_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 105190 | 1000 | 100140 | 230380 | 167456 |
| 2020-01-02 | 91170 | 5000 | 102103 | 228988 | 171698 |
| 2020-01-03 | 79110 | 4000 | 412130 | 215554 | 214412 |
| 2020-01-04 | 130859 | 4000 | 61660 | 331125 | 335510 |

The second one is called `correction`:

| DATE | CORRECTION_INDEX |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 0.458 |
| 2020-01-02 | 0.589 |
| 2020-01-03 | 0.988 |
| 2020-01-04 | 0.477 |

I need to multiply the each column on the "app daily users" by the correction index on the "correction" dataframe.
So in the end I'd have something like this (just a quick example):

| DATE | APP_1 | APP_2 | APP_3 | APP_4 | APP_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 48.180 | 458 | 45864 | 105514 | 76694 |

The values on the columns above are the values on the first dataframe on the jan 1st 2020 times `0.458` with is the correction index for that day. Can you guys help me with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply join on `DATE` then use list comprehension with select expression to apply the multiplication:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

result = app_daily_users.join(correction, ["DATE"], "left").select(
    "DATE",
    *[(F.col(c) * F.col("CORRECTION_INDEX")).alias(c)
      for c in app_daily_users.columns if c != "DATE"
      ]
)
```